# chai assertion always OK

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to testing a node.js api with mocha and chai assertion.

My problem is that I always get a 'passed result'.

The test:

```
describe('TESTING /register', () => {

it('Should create a new account for chai-testing:chai-testing', () => {
    let user = {
        pseudo: "chai-testing",
        mail: "chai@chai.com",
        password: "chai-testing"
    };

    chai.request(server)
    .post('/register')
    .send(user)
    .end((err, resp) => {
        console.log(resp.body);
        resp.body.should.have.property('success').eql(true);
        done();
    });
});
});
```

And the console output :

```
  TESTING /register
✓ Should create a new account for chai-testing:chai-testing
```

chai-testing chai@chai.com chai-testing

```
1 passing (51ms)

{ favoris: [],
  _id: 5abf6b5502c0f910439fec32,
  pseudo: 'chai-testing',
  mail: 'chai@chai.com',
  password: '$2a$10$BPzQfp3wiDxU3mwgeXkG8Oh.B1ET8wTt5kg12oBwQ0obUxAyZQdLu',
  admin: false,
  __v: 0 }
POST /register 200 281.742 ms - 51
{ **success: false**, message: 'pseudo already taken' }
```

What I did do wrong in my test?

Comment: Your test is missing an assert for evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

put there two assertion instead of this :

```
describe('TESTING /register', () => {

it('Should create a new account for chai-testing:chai-testing', () => {
   let user = {
    pseudo: "chai-testing",
    mail: "chai@chai.com",
    password: "chai-testing"
  };

chai.request(server)
.post('/register')
.send(user)
.end((err, resp) => {
    console.log(resp.body);
    // if the resp has an attribute success then this
    // assertion is true ( .eql(true) )  
    // that's why you get the test always passing 
    resp.body.should.have.property('success');

    resp.body.success.should.eql(true);
    done();
     });
    });
   });
```